# Is it possible to convert a jpg file into lyr

Tags: arcgis-10.0, convert, jpg, layer-file

I am a beginner with GIS 10.0. IS there any way to convert a jpg file into a layer? 
I am working on a problem that needs to have the entire map of my city as a layer but I just have a jpg file of the map.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. It sounds like you want to convert or add to the data that is in the jpg file. you want other "layers" to go with it? We would call those features classes or data sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you Add Data > Select a basemap to import
You can georeference the JPG to the basemap...
This will create a minor distortion depending on your level of precision and patience, you can  then save the georeferenced image out as a permanently rectified image or as the original image but associated with the georeferencing information.

There are a ton of tutorials and videos on this.. here is one example I pulled from YouTube... Not taking credit for the tutorial video (http://library.tamu.edu/maps-gis)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHtxbpboDro